# Uses of interrogatives as pronouns

Tags: translation, grammar, word-choice

In English, interrogatives are occasionally used as not as interrogatives but as adverbs and relative pronouns. For example: I don't know **why** we moved; I don't know **how** that machine works; I know **where** she lives; I don't know **what** she does for a living； I don't know **whom** she married. Could you use 为什么，怎么，哪里，什么，谁 here, and if not, how would you structure these and similar sentences? 谢谢!

Answer (score 1):

You'll never be able to map one to one English to Chinese, but some things are expressed in a very similar manner in both languages, simply because that is convenient and efficient, I believe.

Relative clauses in Chinese don't follow the English pattern though.

That is the dog [that bit me].
这是那条[咬我的]狗。(Just stick the relative clause content in front of the noun)

I don't know why we moved.
我不晓得我们为什么搬家。
I don't know how that machine works.
我不知道那台机器怎么运作。
I know where she lives.
我不知道她住在哪里。
I don't know what she does for a living.
我不知道她靠什么生活。
I don't know who she married.
我不知道她和谁结的婚。

Answer (score 1):

There are some non standard such use in speakings, for example

> 我不知道**为什么**他就不理我了
>
> 我想问问她**哪**能买到这么好吃的包子
>
> 你能解释一下**谁**吃了我的盒饭吗？

You may not want to write those in a formal text.

Comment: They're not *non-standard*, but they're just *informal*.

Comment: @iBug You are probably right.

Answer (score 0):

interrogative pronouns used for other than questions, cf。＂汉语语法基础＂吕冀平 著 商务印书馆 疑问代词有时候并不真正表示疑问，而是通过它表示反诘或者强调。如：（２９）关汉卿：老王，人家真心实意找你帮忙，别开玩笑！王和卿：谁跟你开玩笑！这事让朱四姐出面，你就免开尊口！（田汉，关汉卿）（３０）小孩子家知道什么！（３１）哪里会有这种事情！这种句子句末常常不用问号而用感叹号。

**有时侯，疑问代词只指不确定的人、事物等等，这样用的时候也不表示疑问。如：（３２）您写得太晚了，又冷又饿，家里可又没什么吃的。（田汉，关汉卿）（３３）这么冷的天，也不知道谁还把窗子打开了。这样的句子句末不能用问号。**

疑问代词还能够表示概括，这样用的时候也不表示疑问。如：（３４）你什么都知道，我真佩服！（３５）一定不会！谁也不会说你们。（３６）是啊，真是叫人高兴，以前我算白活了好些年，哪儿也没有去瞧过。（田汉，关汉卿）